# How to mock aiomysql pool to return a mocked connection object?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-asyncio, aio

I'm trying to write unit test cases for one of my module which uses the aiomysql pool to interface with the MariaDB. I'm trying to mock the database calls for the unit test. I'm using asynctest python module to mock.

I've tried to mock the connect method in aiomysql.pool module. The result of which is that it's returning a NoneType object for the Connection.

```py
def test_new(self):
        with asynctest.patch('pcli.appliances.xyzdb.aiomysql.pool.connect', autospec=True) as mock_connect:
            reader = asynctest.MagicMock()
            reader.at_eof.return_value = False
            conn_obj = asynctest.MagicMock()
            conn_obj._reader = reader
            mock_connect.return_value = asynctest.MagicMock()
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            apps = yield from get_all_appliances()
```

I expect the connection object to be an instance of MagicMock that can be extended by adding necessary attributes.

Comment: Hey Abhishek, have you actually found a solution for this one? I'd be curious, too :)

Comment: Not yet. I ended up running an actual functional test inside a container setup with docker-compose.

Comment: connect is under aiomysql.connection?